# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want some help with a program it's giving an error in python says TypeError: 'int' object is not callable. I want to know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance

```
from math import sqrt
from math import pi

ba = pi * 2( 2 + sqrt(3**2 + 2**2)))

print (ka)
```

Comment: `2( 2` -> `2 * ( 2 `

Comment: @vaultah thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write

```
2(...)
```

it won't work. The interpreter thinks you are trying to call a function called `2`.

If you mean multiplication, use `*`, the python operator for multiplication.

```
2*(...)
```