# Int object is not callable error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to graph a fuction using matplotlib in Jupyter notebooks in python. My code is below. I don't understand why I am getting the error message, which refers to the line with the formula in it y = ...
Here is my code:

```
d = [ ]
e = [ ]

for x in range(-4, 4, 1):
    y= -16(x**2)+20(x)+50
    d.append(x)
    e.append(y)

fig= plt.figure()
axes=fig.add_subplot(111)
axes.plot(d,e)
plt.show()
```

Comment: you forgot to add `*` it should be `y= -16*(x**2)+20*(x)+50`

Comment: You write `-16(x**2)` so Python thinks you call `16(..)` (with some arguments).

Comment: The syntax `20(x)` tells python to execute the special `__call__()` method on the integer `20`, which doesn't exist.  This is not a proper syntax for multiplication.  Try `20*x` instead.

Comment: just a style note you shouldn't put a space between brackets like `[ ]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'int' object is not callable python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478298/typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable-python)

Answer (score 0):

In python a multiplication is done via an asterix, `2 * 2`, or `2*(2*4)`.

Hence the line in question should read

```
y= -16*(x**2)+20*x+50
```

Note that you would normally use numpy for such things.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-4, 4)
y= -16*(x**2)+20*x+50

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig= plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is:

```
y= -16(x**2)+20(x)+50
```

You write `-16(..)` and `20(..)` but this is syntax for *calling* a function (like `sin(2)`). So Python aims to "*call*" `16`, but this fails.

You can solve it by writing asterisks (`*`) between the two:

```
y= -16*(x**2) + 20*x + 50
```

Or:

```
y= -16*x*x + 20*x + 50
```

although the syntax looks a bit similar to mathematics, there are some differences. For instance curly braces (`{}`) are used for sets and dictionaries, and square brackets (`[]`) are used for lists and indexing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that () are associated with function/method calls, not simple multiplication that you might be used to on paper.

Modify that line to:

```
y= -16 * (x**2) + 20 * (x) + 50
```